# Synchronize bindingList, DevExpress gridControl and database

Tags: c#, data-binding, n-tier-architecture

We have an application that uses three-tier architecture (client, server, database). On the client side there is a devexpress gridControl which is used to modify data . Its datasource is bindingList. The question is how to synchronize three entities:bindingList, gridView and database.
We tried to hook up to bindingListChanged event when the new item is added but we faced a problem. This event is fired immediately after first key has been entered in the New Item Row. In that moment there is no data we can send to our database. Can you help us? What are the best practices to solve that kind of problem?

Thank you.
Looking forward for reply.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I don't know about Devexpress grid, but you would call databind() on the gridview (ASP.NET default one) after you insert records in your database. So after every insert the gridview binds & fetches the new records to display.

Comment: I'll try to make the question more general.
If there are:
1. public CRUD API on server side that interact with database via ORM
2. gridControl on client side with bindingList as its datasource 

User on client-side can modify records in gridControl. All changes must be saved to database on server side by calling the API.

What's the best practice to link CRUD operations on server side with gridControl and bindingList on client side.

We are using Winforms-based client + WCF API + NHibernate